# Can't make Xamarin.Auth redirect back to device

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-mobile-services, xamarin.auth

I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/oauth/) to authenticate with Azure AD for my Azure Mobile Service but I can't get the URL redirect working. Maybe I have misunderstood but this is what I have tried ...

**In the iOS project**
I added this URL Scheme to info.plist: `com.spike.Xamarin.OAuth:/oauth2redirect`
I override the `AppDelegate.OpenUrl` method(s) (both overloads) and implement the code from the tutorial

**In the PCL project**
I pass the authentication URL as `https://(my service).azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad` and as the redirect URL I pass the same URL (above) to the `Xamarin.Auth.OAuth2Authenticator` ctor.
I add an event handler to the `Xamarin.Auth.OAuth2Authenticator.Completed` event, to fetch the access token and so on.

**In my protected Azure Mobile service** (AAD / Express)
I registered the above URL reversed: `OAuth.Xamarin.spike.com:/oauth2redirect` as an 'ALLOWED EXTERNAL REDIRECT URLS'.

**Result**

What happens is I get to the login page and I am able to fill in my credentials as expected. But the final redirect never hits the AppDelegate.OpenUrl method. Instead iOS Safari seems to end up at `https://(my service).azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`.

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance ?

Comment: Hi Bruce. I'm currently trying to work out your instructions but so far I have been unable to make it work. That might be because of me however. Thanks alo for taking the time!

Comment: After entering your credentials do you get the error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in the web browser ? ( I am having this issue )

Answer (score 3):

[Xamarin.Auth](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth) includes OAuth authenticators that provide support for consuming identity providers (e.g. Google, Microsoft, Facebook, and Twitter,etc.).

Per my understanding, you could leverage the **Xamarin.Auth** SDK to independently contact the identity provider and retrieve the access token on your mobile client side, then you need to login with your backend (azure mobile app) along with the token for retrieving the `authenticationToken`, then you could leverage the `authenticationToken` to access the resources under your mobile app.

For Azure AD authentication, you could refer to the following settings for constructing the `OAuth2Authenticator` as follows:

**Authorize URL** to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}`

**Redirect URL** to `{Client-ID-of-your-AD-app}:/oauth2redirect`

**AccessToken Url** to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token`

For more details, you could refer to [OAuth 2.0 authorization flow for AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#oauth-20-authorization-flow).

After retrieved the access token from AAD, you need to send the following request for logging with your mobile app:

```
Post: https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad
payload: {"access_token":"{your-access-token}"}
```

Additionally, you could also leverage [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/) for [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow) or [Server-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow). For more details about adding authentication to your app, you could refer to [Add authentication to the portable class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#add-authentication-to-the-portable-class-library) and [Add authentication to the iOS app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#add-authentication-to-the-ios-app)  for your Xamarin Forms app.